# iframe 404 error

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, http-status-code-404

Hi have a few iframes on a page. Each appears when respective tab is clicked. Initially when page is loaded first tab is selected and first iframe is shown. Now, I have initialized all my iframes to javascript:void(0) i.e. to avoid slow loading of the page. When user clicks on a tab then the respective iframe is initialized to each different page. But since the content is little heavy a 404 Not found page is shown for some time.

How to avoid this? can we show a plain background instead of 404 error. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Related to dealing with 404 errors the following could also be useful for anyone finding this in search: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499117/how-to-detect-an-error-404-in-an-iframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't initialize the iframe to anything.  Just omit the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a custom 404 page with whatever you want on it.

about all you need for the page is:

```
<html><head><title>loading</title></head>
<body style="background-color:blue;color:white">
<h2>Loading...</h2>
</body</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle 404 error by defining in deployment descriptor. If you are in Java you can define in web.xml as follows,   `<error-page>
        <error-code>
            404
        </error-code>
        <location>
            /404.html
        </location>
    </error-page>`