# How to detect an error 404 in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, http-status-code-404

My Web page uses iframes to collect content from other pages. All pages are in the same domain.

From the main page, is there a way to confirm that all iframes have loaded, and that there is no 404 error?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375710/detect-failure-to-load-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: @Slytael indeed this is a similar question... but 5 years old and with no valid answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect iframe load error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222314/detect-iframe-load-error)

Comment: A previous question with useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222314/detect-iframe-load-error

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela unfortunately this won't work for me. I need a JavaScript solution, no php.

Comment: @Christophe, the question is still a duplicate of some older questions, at least one of which has a useful answer. And the correct answer appears to be that you cannot do this with JavaScript (alone).

Comment: Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267010/how-can-i-detect-whether-an-iframe-is-loaded

Comment: @HerbalMart unfortunately this won't help with the 404 error.

Comment: @Christophe Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### The status only lives in the response header.

The 404 Page is handling an [HTTP Status Code](http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml), which is only included in the server's response sent to the browser, but not in the actual `window` and `document` objects of the DOM that javascript may access. This means that while you certainly can collect the status-code and take appropriate actions, you may only do so when your javascript is receiving the response, such as with a [jQuery.ajax() request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863062/detect-http-301-status-code-from-javascript) or an [XmlHttRequest to load your "iframe"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419343/1589379).

#### Hope the 404 page follows 404 standards.

If the above isn't an option, the only other possibility may be to check the title, and/or H tags, for " 404 ". While this is most certainly less than ideal (I'd love to see, "404, Movie not Found, the Movie."), it is your only other option.

```
$('#iframe').load(function (e) {
    var iframe = $("#iframe")[0];

    if ( iframe.innerHTML() ) {
        // get and check the Title (and H tags if you want)
        var ifTitle = iframe.contentDocument.title;
        if ( ifTitle.indexOf("404")>=0 ) {
            // we have a winner! probably a 404 page!
        }
    } else {
        // didn't load
    }
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer but i don't understand why they did not implement this tiny but usefull feature

Comment: While it would be useful, it could also be easily abused. At the end of the day, header content is in the header because it is critical to both the connection, and security, between the server and client.

Comment: I suppose this will only work if document in Iframe is on the same domain?

Comment: what about cross domain?

Comment: This is intended for cross domain. If you're talking about cross domain scripting in iframes, javascript, or similar, you're out of luck unless you own those domains. If that is the case, there are other threads for such discussions.

Comment: @TimoHuovinen For cross domain document see 2nd part of my answer.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use `this` instead of `var iframe = $("#iframe")[0];`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, absolutely.

Comment: It does not work with domains of different origin, unfortunately

Comment: @silvanasono, if you own those domains, you can with CORS and/or Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers. If you do not, then use the answer mirmdasif 
provided below. I would note with his answer, that since you'll have the whole HTML in that ajax response, you could just update the DOM rather than making another request by loading the iframe.

Answer (score 20):

Suppose this is your html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
    </body>
 </html>
```

There are two scenario

1. Your iframe's src is in the same domain from where your page is originated.

   ```
   Ex : page url www.example.com and iframe's src www.example.com/iframe
   ```

   You can use jQuery ajax request to check if the the resource is available

   ```
      $(function() {
           $.ajax({
               type : "HEAD",
               async : true,
               url : "www.example.com/iframe"
           })
           .success(function() {
               $("#iframe").attr("src", "www.example.com/iframe");
           })
           .error(function(){
              // Handle error perhaps a failover url
           })
       });
   ```
2. Your iframe's src is not pointing to the same domain from where your page was originated.

   ```
   Ex : Page url www.example.com and iframe's src www.otherdomain.com/iframe
   ```

   Now browsers will not let you make a cross site request from javascript code due to [cross origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). The way around is to make a [jsonp request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

   ```
   $(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: "www.otherdomain.com/iframe",
           dataType: "jsonp",
           timeout: 5000,

           success: function () {
               $("#iframe").attr("src", "www.otherdomain.com/iframe");
           },
           error: function (parsedjson) {
               if(parsedjson.status == "200") {
                   $("#iframe").attr("src", "www.otherdomain.com/iframe");
               } else {
                   // Handle error
               }
           }
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: part 2 is very interesting, never thought of that.

Comment: Recently faced that issue had to solve it in a different way :)

Comment: Not a bad solution, but if you're using jQuery ajax to grab the content anyway, why use iframes at all, and why force the iframe to re-run the same request you just made with ajax?

Instead, just grab the content of the ajax response, and put it into the page. Finish using the ajax object to create a complete AJAX solution.

Comment: If it is a cross domain request then it would not be possible.

Comment: @MirMd.AsifHossain make the AJAX request to your own server, have the server request the url and return the result as the Ajax response. You then have the entire content body to operate on... I guess that would be out of scope for this discussion though.

Comment: @Tony Chiboucas That's another way. But then you have to deal with servers firewall allowing the requested URL. Also you may not have any backend as well. If that's the case you have to deal with it in client side.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas you can't put content in iframe other that calling `src=url_address` at least not in traditional way. If you want to put content in iframe I suppose you can accomplish that by writing some javascript that does that. With ajax approach you can for sure know when error occured and display proper message. Otherwise if error occured iframe still displays error, how does the user differ? The error could potentially be the message

Comment: @broadband What I'm saying is that if you're going so far as to pull the content via an AJAX request, why not simply have your server make the request, and not bother with the iframe at all. Your server can parse and clean the body of the response, and send it as the response to the AJAX request, which then you could simply load into a div, or straight into the body of the frame.

Comment: In an enterprise software making server calling a new url is not always straightforward. You need to deal with  firewall and stuffs.

Comment: Does not work in Firefox and Safari, they throw error on loading html with script

Comment: In the second part, I'd like to point out that `parsedjson.status` actually has value in `Number` not `String` so that `if` statement will always result in `false`.

Comment: @VeerakranSereerungruangkul actually no. It's not a strict check like (200 === "200")

You can try this code in browser console.
console.log(200 == "200")

Comment: @mirmdasif You're right. This is my mistake. I got used to using `===` all the time.

Comment: I don't understand, so does this still as of 2021 work in chrome for cross domain requests? I've not been able to get it to work.      ```fetchJsonp("https://www.youtube.com").then(function(response) {return response.json()
}).then(function(json) {console.log('parsed json', json)}).catch(function(ex) {console.log('parsing failed', ex)})``` gives error: ```parsing failed Error: JSONP request to https://www.youtube.com timed out at fetch-jsonp.js:91```