# Error handling in iframe-resizer?

Tags: javascript, iframe-resizer

I use [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) to insert content(jsf-pages) in iframe.
So, how to detect that server responsed with 404 not found?

Is there some callback or other way to detect this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect an error 404 in an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499117/how-to-detect-an-error-404-in-an-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 const iframeResizerOptions = {
    log: true,
    checkOrigin: true,
    initCallback: (iframe) => {
      if (iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName("error-title").length > 0) {
        onError();
      } else {
        onLoad();
      }
    },
  };
```

You may use initCallback and get iframe from input parameter.